# Call a file in a plugin using AJAX in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, subscribe

I'm using wordpress 3.5 and use a plugin to handle newsletter. I have placed the newsletter widget which consists of one text box for email and one button to subscribe. When the button is clicked, it will be directed to a file called subscribe.php. It is in [wordpress_plugin_directory]/subscribe.php.

I'd like to use AJAX for this subscribtion. When the button is clicked, it will simply call [wordpress_plugin_directory]/subscribe.php and let that file do the works. I have read many articles on how to use AJAX on Wordpress, but it seems like I couldn't get the hang of it.

How do you call that file using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer because you have not shown what you have tried.

Follow the example in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), it works. The further reading articles (particularly on security) are also worth reading and implementing.

The AJAX is going call a function, not open a file (although you could open the file in the function using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) - but that may not be necessary, why not just use the function to return what you need? I don't know what is in subscribe.php so this may or may not be appropriate.

If you still can't get it to work, show what you have tried and where it is failing so a more detailed answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have a form like this

```
<form id="newletterBoxForm" method="POST" action="[wordpress_plugin_directory]/subscribe.php">
    <input type="text" ... />
    <input type="text" ... />
    <input type="submit" ... />
</form>
```

With jQuery you will get the event just before it starts and canceling the action like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newletterBoxForm").on("submit", function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "[wordpress_plugin_directory]/subscribe.php.",
        // get the data of your form
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // if it is ok, do some actions
            alert("ok DONE!")
        },
        error : function(s , i , error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    // cancel normal behaviour which will refresh your page
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This will work, but it is not 'the WordPress way'. Posting straight to subscribe.php removes the availability of WordPress so take extra care with your script to protect against potential XSS (and other) vulnerabilities.

Comment: I think it is completely valid since the form already posts to this url not an other... There's no "extra care".

Comment: As I said, it will work so it is valid in that sense - but it is not the best way. Just because the OP is posting to a stand-alone file already doesn't make it right. Much better to post back to the same page and use the WordPress route with easy nonces and validation functions all to hand.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the url of the form was this one, which can happen for some plugins. I do understand now. He has to follow the action of the current form, obviously.